# CSV to LIBSVM using phraug

Tags: python, csv, svm, libsvm

I try to convert my CSV file to LIBSVM by using phraug python scripts. (https://github.com/zygmuntz/phraug)

Here is my dataset, which contains a label on first position and a header:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/j4wsh5pde76o8ax/adclickwithoutid.csv

I saw a posting here on stackoverflow([Converting CSV file to LIBSVM compatible data file using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23170152/converting-csv-file-to-libsvm-compatible-data-file-using-python)) and tried his code:

```
Alexanders-iMac:documents arigge$ python csv2libsvm.py adclickwithoutid.csv libsvm.data 1 True
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "csv2libsvm.py", line 51, in <module>
    new_line = construct_line( label, line )
  File "csv2libsvm.py", line 15, in construct_line
    if float( item ) == 0.0:
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing the meaning of `4` of the post [Converting CSV file to LIBSVM compatible data file using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23170152/converting-csv-file-to-libsvm-compatible-data-file-using-python)

As I saw your data, the first element seems target. Right? So I tried:

```
python csv2libsvm.py iris.csv libsvm.data 0 True
```

It produced `2G` libsvm data from your `1.4G` csv data.

Comment: I tried your command line but still get following error message:

admin$ python csv2libsvm.py adclickwithoutid.csv libsvm.data 0 True
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "csv2libsvm.py", line 51, in <module>
    new_line = construct_line( label, line )
  File "csv2libsvm.py", line 15, in construct_line
    if float( item ) == 0.0:
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 

Did you maybe do it for the iris.csv file as indicated by your command line?