# Convert text columns csv file to LibSVM or SVMLight format by the vectorization

Tags: svm, libsvm, word2vec, deeplearning4j, svmlight

The CSV with text columns (sentence features in column) to convert it to svmlight or libsvm format (numerical format) by the vectorization like bag of words, etc?

Comment: what is your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the python [csv2libsvm.py](https://github.com/zygmuntz/phraug/blob/master/csv2libsvm.py) file to convert. This issue is the same [Converting CSV file to LIBSVM compatible data file using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23170152/converting-csv-file-to-libsvm-compatible-data-file-using-python)